# Equivalent of underscore.js's find in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, underscore.js

How to do the equivalent of this in jquery?

```
var myCollection = $(".sortable");
var link = _.find(myCollection, function(item){
    return someInput.value == $(item).data("sort-column");
});
```

Comment: What if you explain the original task? stackoverflow.com isn't a code convertion tool

Comment: ps: http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Comment: pps: `[data-sort-column="myFilter"]`

Comment: Try grep - http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/ - only difference is that it doesn't exit after it finds the first match.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var link = $(".sortable[data-sort-column=" + someInput.value + "]");
```

Answer (score 1):

Knowing why you're trying to do this would help, but I don't think there's a built in function to replace for the underscore one. One of the comments mentions `filter`, but that is not the same as underscore's `_.find`, since `find` returns for the first found element.

That's the only suggestion I have, but that's just a forEach

```
  var item 
  $.each(myCollection,function( index, element ) {
    if ( condition ) {
      item = element
      return false
    }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use $.grep 
Finds the elements of an array which satisfy a filter function. The original array is not affected.
https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.grep/

Answer (score -1):

Have you looked at jQuery's [each](http://api.jquery.com/each/)?
You might format it more like:

```
myCollection.each(function( item ) { ... });
```